# Synchronizing pthreads using mutex in C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, mutex

I've got to write a program that counts series of first 10 terms (sorry for my language, this is the first time that I'm talking about math in english) given by formula (x^i)/i!. So, basically it's trivial. BUT, there's some special requirements. Every single term got to be counted by seperated thread, each of them working concurrent. Then all of them got to save results to common variable named *result*. After that they have to be added by main thread, which will display final result. All of it using pthreads and mutexes.

That's where I have a problem. I was thinking about using table to store results, but I was told by teacher, that it's not correct solution, cause then I don't have to use mutexes. Any ideas what to do and how to synchronize it? I'm completely new to pthread and mutex.

Here's what I got till now. I'm still working on it, so it's not working at the moment, it's just a scheme of a program, where I want to add mutexes. I hope it's not all wrong. ;p

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int number = 0;
float result = 0;
pthread_mutex_t term_lock;
pthread_mutex_t main_lock;
int save = 0; //condition variable

int factorial(int x) { 
        if(x==0 || x==1)
                return 1;

        return factorial(x-1)*x;
}

void  *term(void *value) {  
        int x = *(int *)value;
        float w;
        if(save == 0) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&term_lock);
            w = pow(x, number)/factorial(number);
            result = w;
            printf("%d term of series with x: %d  is: %f\n", number, x, w);
            number++;
            save = 1;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&term_lock);
        }
        return NULL;
}

int main(void) {

        int x, i, err = 0;
        float final = 0;
        pthread_t threads[10];

        pthread_attr_t attr;
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

        printf("Get X: \n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
                err = pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, (void *)term, &x);
                if(err) {
                        printf("Error creating threads.\n");
                        exit(-1);
                }
        }
        i = 0;
        while (number <= 10) {
            //printf("While Result: %f, final %f\n", result, final); - shows that it's infinite loop
            if(save) {
                pthread_mutex_lock(&main_lock); 
                final = final + result;
                save = 0;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&main_lock);   
                printf("If Result: %f, final %f\n", result, final); //final == last result
            }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

EDIT: If it's not clear - I need help with solution how to store results of all threads in common variable and synchronizing it.

EDIT2: Possible solution - global variable `result` shared by all threads. Returned to main thread, it would be added to some local variable, so then I could just overwrite it's value with result from another thread. Of course it will require some synchronization, so another thread won't overwrite it before I add it in main thread. What do you think?

EDIT3: I've updated code with what I have right now. Output is giving me me values of 8-9 terms (printf in term), then program is still working, showing nothing. Commented printf showed me, that while loop is infinite. Also local variable final has just last value of result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm confused.  You suggest "add `result += result;` in function term", which is quite reasonable, but you earlier said that the individual terms "have to be added *by main thread*" (emphasis added).  These are not compatible.

Comment: Damn, sorry, still forgetting about that. You're right, I can't do that.

Comment: Just a FYI on the values: term(x) is being called with x=NULL, so `pow(x,number)` is same as `pow(0,number)` which is always zero.

Comment: You are almost right, @Soren, `pow(0, 0)` is `1`. Now, for the mathematical reason for that, I have to pass. I personally find it very disturbing, but I remember that it is more consistent for some reason.

Comment: JayL, you should give each thread a structure (via a pointer) that tells it what data to work with and where to store the result. Then, you simply join the threads in main and add up the results there. That way, zero additional synchronization is required.

Comment: I don't think a mutex is needed here. Each thread[i] can calculate it's term and store the value in result[i], then return to terminate. Main can then loop with pthread_join(threads[i]) to wait for all 10 threads to complete, then sum up the values in result[].

Comment: @rcgldr, certainly the task could be accomplished without a mutex, but it is an academic exercise whose conditions demand that a mutex be used.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - Since the requirement is for all 10 threads to run concurrently,and apparently store their terms in result[10], so that main then sum up the terms, then one approach would be to use 10 mutexes, that main locks, and the 10 threads unlock (just before terminating), but that's not the way a mutex is normally used.

Comment: Like @JohnBollinger said, it is an academic exercise. I could do it without mutexes, even without threads, but it's not what I have to do. And also about first term of series - I know that it will always be 1, but I have to count first ten terms with seperate threads, so that's including the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rather contrived that the main thread should be the one to add the terms, but the individual threads must all write their results to the same variable.  I would ordinarily expect each thread to add its own term to the result (which does require mutex), or possibly to put its result in an array (as you suggested), or to add it to a shared queue (which would require mutex), or even to write it to a pipe.  Nevertheless, it can be done your teacher's way.

One of the key problems to solve is that you have to distinctly different operations that you need to synchronize:

- The various computational threads' writes to the shared result variable
- The main thread's reads of the result variable

You cannot use just a single synchronization construct because you cannot that way distinguish between the computational threads and the main thread.  One way to approach this would be to synchronize the computational threads' writes via a mutex, as required, and to synchronize those *vs*. the main thread's reads via semaphores or condition variables.  You could also do it with one or more additional mutexes, but not cleanly.

Additional notes:

- the result variable in which your threads deposit their terms must be a global.  Threads do not have access to the local variables of the function from which they are launched.
- the signature of your `term()` function is incorrect for a thread start function.  The argument must be of type `void *`.
- thread start functions are no different from other functions in that their local variables are accessible only for the duration of the function execution.  In particular, returning a pointer to a local variable cannot do anything useful, as any attempt to later dereference such a pointer produces undefined behavior.

I'm not going to write your homework for you, but here's an approach that can work:

1. The main thread initializes a mutex and two semaphores, the latter with initial values zero.
2. The main thread launches all the computational threads.  Although it's ugly, you can feed them their numeric arguments by casting those to `void *`, and then casting them back in the `term()` function (since its argument should be a `void *`).
3. The main thread then loops.  At each iteration, it

   1. waits for semaphore 1 (`sem_wait()`)
   2. adds the value of the global `result` variable to a running total
   3. posts to semaphore 2 (`sem_post()`)
   4. if as many iterations have been performed as there are threads, breaks from the loop

Meanwhile, each computational thread does this:

1. Computes the value of the appropriate term
2. locks the mutex
3. stores the term value in the global `result` variable
4. posts to semaphore 1
5. waits for semaphore 2
6. unlocks the mutex

**Update:**

To use condition variables for this job, it is essential to identify which shared state is being protected by those condition variables, as one must always protect against waking spurriously from a wait on a condition variable.

In this case, it seems natural that the shared state in question would involve the global `result` variable in which the computational threads return their results.  There are really two general, mutually exclusive states of that variable:

1. Ready to receive a value from a computational thread, and
2. Ready for the main thread to read.

The computational threads need to wait for the first state, and the main thread needs to wait (repeatedly) for the second.  Since there are two different conditions that threads will need to wait on, you need two condition variables.  Here's an alternative approach using these ideas:

1. The main thread initializes a mutex and two condition variables, and sets `result` to `-1`.
2. The main thread launches all the computational threads.  Although it's ugly, you can feed them their numeric arguments by casting those to `void *`, and then casting them back in the `term()` function (since its argument should be a `void *`).
3. The main thread locks the mutex
4. The main thread then loops.  At each iteration, it

   1. tests whether `result` is non-negative.  If so, it

      1. adds the value of `result` variable to a running total
      2. if as many terms have been added as there are threads, breaks from the loop
      3. sets `result` to `-1`.
      4. signals condition variable 1
   2. waits on condition variable 2
5. Having broken from the loop, the main thread unlocks the mutex

Meanwhile, each computational thread does this:

1. Computes its term
2. Locks the mutex
3. Loops:

   1. Checks the value of `result`.  If it is less than zero then breaks from the loop
   2. waits on condition variable 1
4. Having broken from the loop, sets `result` to the computed term
5. signals condition variable 2
6. unlocks the mutex

Comment: Thanks for all this help, I really appreciate it. I think I got this part with mutexes by now, but I have never used semaphores, so again I've got a problem how to use it. But I'll try to work something out, thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can use semaphores (we'll be talking about it on next class), so can you tell more about how to do it with condition variable? I'm trying to use it, but 1) not all threads are displaying their values, 2) variable in main, that should have been adding all values has just one last value of global result. I'll show what I got in my main post.

Comment: Updated with an approach using condition variables instead of semaphores (and still using a mutex, which condition variables require).

Answer (score 0):

The `number` is shared between all the threads, so you will need to protect that with a mutex (which is probably what your teacher is wanting to see)

```
pthread_mutex_t number_mutex;
pthread_mutex_t result_mutex;
int number = 0;
int result = 0;

void  *term(int x) {
  float w;

  // Critical zone, make sure only one thread updates `number`
  pthread_mutex_lock(&number_mutex); 
  int mynumber = number++;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&number_mutex);
  // end of critical zone 

  w = pow(x, mynumber)/factorial(mynumber);
  printf("%d term of series with x: %d  is: %f\n", mynumber, x, w);

  // Critical zone, make sure only one thread updates `result`
  pthread_mutex_lock(&result_mutex); 
  result += w;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&result_mutex);
  // end of critical zone 

  return (void *)0;
}
```

You should also remove the DETACHED state and do a thread-join at the end of your main program before printing out the result

Comment: Unfotrunately I have to use detached threads, it's another requirement. Now I am thinking, is sharing `number` reasonable? Maybe I should create table with numbers 0-9 and just pass it to threads. 

Now I started to think about another solution - make global variable `result` for all threads and set it in critical zone. After thread is finished it would return value to main thread, which would store it in another, local variable. Then I could just overwrite `result` with another threads and main thread would just be adding (+=) new values to value of that local variable.

Comment: That is a possibility to have a single `result` instead of an array and set that in a critical zone as well -- assuming that fits your requirement.
How will you know the threads are all finished? Does it matter?

Comment: You are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer (`result`); the behavior is undefined.  If you do return a pointer to the result, then it needs to be a pointer to global storage (not to a local variable).  In that case, either the global storage either must be unique to the thread, or access to *that* must be synchronized.

Comment: @JohnBollinger -- yeahh, I fixed that -- it was just an error cut-n-paste from OP question

Comment: In any case, this seems to be sidestepping the problem.  It does use a mutex, but not for the purpose described in the problem (synchronizing access to the computational threads' *results*).

Comment: @Soren, you now appear to have implemented exactly the solution that the OP says his teacher would not allow: to record the results in an array (though he used the word "table").

Comment: @JohnBollinger -- I think that is a matter of interpretation -- He was not allowed NOT to use mutexes -- but that is an easy fix, the OP suggested how to do it himself, and I will update

Comment: Now it's almost what I need, with one exception - final result must be updated in main thread. And I have to use mutexes - this is what I have to learn by this task. :) So in this case I think that I have to change `result += w` to just `result = w` and then update some local variable in main with next value of global variable `result`. But I still can't get how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to your problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int number=0;
float result[10];
pthread_mutex_t lock;

int factorial(int x) {


    if(x==0 || x==1)
                return 1;

        return factorial(x-1)*x;
}

void  *term(void *value) {
        int x = *(int *)value;
        float w;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        w = pow(x, number)/factorial(number);
        printf("%d term of series with x: %d  is: %f\n", number, x, w);
        result[number] = w;
        number++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        return NULL;
}

int main(void) {

        int x, i, err;
        pthread_t threads[10];

        printf("Get X: \n"); 
        scanf("%d", &x);

        for(i=0; i<=9; i++)
        {
                err = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, term, &x);
                if(err) {
                        printf("Error creating threads.\n");
                        exit(-1);
                }
        }

        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
                pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        }

        i = 0;

        for(i=0; i<=9; i++)
        {
                printf("%f\n", result[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

This code creates a global mutex `pthread_mutex_t lock` that (in this case) makes sure that same code is not executed by anyone at the same time: basically when one thread executes `pthread_mutex_lock(&lock)`, it forbids any other `thread` from executing that part of the code until the "original" thread executes `pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock)`.

The other important part is `pthread_join`: what this does is force the main thread to wait for the execution of every other thread created; this way, `float result[10]` is written before actually being worked on in the main thread (in this case, the last print instruction).

Other than that, I fixed a couple of bugs in your code that other users pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think that this code does not meet the requirements that I got. Pthreads can't be joinable. Also, you're storing results of function `term` in global array, which I can't do. All pthreads has to return values to one common variable, which would be critical zone. Also thanks for fixing other bugs, I wasn't sure how to apply those suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If result is to be a single variable, then one solution is to use an array of 20 mutexes: aMutex[20];. Main locks all 20 mutexes then starts the pthreads. Each pthread[i] computes a local term, waits for aMutex[i], stores it's value into result, then unlocks aMutex[10+i]. In main() for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){ unlock aMutex[i] to allow pthread[i] to store its value into result, then wait for aMutex[10+i] to know that result is updated, then add result to a sum. }